# Rails sum of one to many error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm has books. Each book has list of chapters. Each chapter has text. I'm need calculate total value of characters. I'm wrote such code:

```
symbols = 0
b.chapters.all.each do |c|
    symbols += c.text.length
end
```

And that's work fine. But, when i wrought:

```
symbols = b.chapters.all.sum(:text.length)
```

It's return invalid count of chars. Did anyone has any suggestion where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write using the block verion of [`#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) :

```
b.chapters.sum { |c| c.text.length }
```

This is wrong : `b.chapters.all.sum(:text.length)`

Because - `:text.length` gives you the length of symbol `:text` as `4`. And the 4 is summed up **n** times, where **n** is the size of the collection `b.chapters`.

I tried with the data as I have in my project :

```
[21] pry(main)> Menu.first.dishes.count # => 5
[22] pry(main)> Menu.first.dishes.map { |d| d.dish_type.size } # => [9, 7, 5, 7, 6]
[23] pry(main)> Menu.first.dishes.sum { |d| d.dish_type.size } # => 34
```

I have `has_many` association between `Dish` and `Menu`. Now see the below another thing, which made your fool :

```
 Menu.first.dishes.sum(:a.size) # => 5
```

Comment: I'm tried such variant, but it's raise such exception: "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"

>b.chapters.sum { |c| c.text.length }

Comment: Thanks a lot about explanation of my problem. I'm waste a lot of time to understand why i'ts return 12.

Comment: It's look very dump, but in my project map work's fine, and sum isn't work. I think maybe trouble in ruby or rail's version. At least, i solved it's by wright "
b.chapters.map{ |c| c.text.length }.reduce(:+)" 
But honestly, it's look not better than previous my solution. Thanks for answers!